# Naive star filter visible at night in certain country

Tags: star

I have a HYG catalogue and I'd like to filter out stars visible at night and in Europe.

Doesn't have to be exact. I was assuming that it'll be all stars with positive declination, but I wasn't sure about RA values.

Thanks, Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/26787 you can find an example how to convert celestial coordinates to horizon coordinates an than check, if the altitude is above the horizon

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I'm probably going to use PyEphem for this

Comment: I did and it worked great. One comment for future followers - if you're crosschecking alt/az with Stellarium (for example), don't forget that pyephem works in UTC timezone by default while Stellarium uses yours....too me a few hours to realize this